# How to use SOUNDS LIKE in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, activerecord

Codeigniter Active records query gives me error. how to put SOUNDS LIKE into where clause.

```
function _search($type, $q, $qes, $sort = null, $start = 0) {
    $type = strtolower($type);
    $q = strtolower($q);


    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from("books");
    $this->db->where("SOUNDEX(name) IN({$q})");
    foreach($qes as $k){
        $this->db->or_where("name SOUNDS LIKE '$k'");
    }
    foreach($qes as $k){
        $this->db->or_where("name LIKE '%$k%'");
    }
    $this->db->where("status", 1);
    if ($type != NULL) {
        $this->db->where("LOWER(type)", $type);
    }
    //$this->db->like("LOWER(name)", $q);

    $this->db->limit(BWK_MAX_BOOK_SIZE, $start);
    switch ($sort) {
        case 1:
            break;
        case 2:
            $this->db->order_by("sellingPrice", "ASC");
            break;
        case 3:
            $this->db->order_by("sellingPrice", "DESC");
            break;
        case 4:
            $this->db->order_by("created", "DESC");
            break;
  }
```

this gives me query when i echo query. i am searching for **technologi** i need to get technology technologies etc.

```
SELECT * FROM `books` WHERE SOUNDEX(name) IN('t254') OR `name` `SOUNDS` LIKE 'technolog' OR `name` LIKE '%technologi%' AND `status` = 1 AND LOWER(type) = 'school' LIMIT 50
```

getting error

```
  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '`SOUNDS` LIKE 'technolog' OR `name` LIKE '%technolog%' AND `status` = 1 AND LOWE' at line 4
```

every thing works fine but when i put SOUNDS LIKE it gives me error.

Comment: Remove the backticks from SOUNDS

Comment: @Bart how do i remove. i have not put backticks it automatically takes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its probably the best to group things here

you can try the following

```
$this->db
    ->select('*')
    ->from('books')
    ->where_in('SOUNDEX(name)', $q,  NULL);

if (is_array($qes) && count($qes) > 0)
{
    $this->db->group_start();
    foreach($qes AS $k)
    {
        $this->db->or_group_start();
            $this->db
                ->where('name SOUNDS LIKE '.$this->db->escape($k), NULL, false)
                ->or_like('name', $k);

        $this->db->group_end();
    }
    $this->db->group_end();
}

if (!is_null($type))
{
    $this->db->where('LOWER(type)', $type);
}

switch ($sort) {
    case 1:
        break;
    case 2:
        $this->db->order_by("sellingPrice", "ASC");
        break;
    case 3:
        $this->db->order_by("sellingPrice", "DESC");
        break;
    case 4:
        $this->db->order_by("created", "DESC");
        break;
}

echo $this->db
    ->where('status',1)
    ->limit(BWK_MAX_BOOK_SIZE, $start)
    ->get_compiled_select();
```

this would produce a statement like

```
SELECT *
FROM `books`
WHERE SOUNDEX(name) IN('t254') AND
(
    (
        name SOUNDS LIKE 'technologi' OR 
        `name` LIKE '%technologi%' ESCAPE '!'
    ) 
    OR 
    (
        name SOUNDS LIKE 'whatever' OR 
        `name` LIKE '%whatever%' ESCAPE '!'
    )
)
AND `status` = 1
AND LOWER(type) = 'school' 
LIMIT 50
```

Comment: it gives me [] result but in my db there are words name technology, technologies etc

Comment: maybe there are words with technology in there - but are they also with soundex(name) T254 ? - you should gv us a snapshot of your db with the affected rows - because it looks like even you dont know what you want;)

Answer (score 0):

**From : DB_query_builder.php**, what one can see is 3rd argument decides whether to escape or not.

```
public function or_where($key, $value = NULL, $escape = NULL){

}
```

So just tell that not to escape it

```
$this->db->or_where("name SOUNDS LIKE '$k'", NULL, FALSE);
```

Comment: error gone but not able to search proper result. like technology, technologies etc

Comment: Use where_in with 3rd argument or use 3rd argument in your where clause

Answer (score 0):

Could you use the HAVING clause with your ORDER BY and your LIKE?

HAVING clause:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp